Elementor template shortcode gives error after running post query
I run the elementor template shortcode inside a custom query, and it shows the intended posts but then shows "No posts found" and the content of the first one, plus doesnt show the rest of the sections of the page that were after this query.
It should just show the arquive template, without the random post content. I'm have to use a custom query because it has to exclude and include certain post ids which is what is inside the array $highs.
Here's what I'm trying:
query_posts(array(
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'post',
    'post__in'      => $highs
));
    if(have_posts()){

    return '[elementor-template id="34888"]';   //"[elementor-template id='34851']";
  

    }
      wp_reset_postdata(); ;
        wp_reset_query();
    

And this is what I get:
Failled attempt
The problem is its like the query is not closing, its still getting results from it.
Any help is appreciated, thanks.

return will exit the current function at this point, so if that if condition was true, then wp_reset_postdata and wp_reset_query won't execute at all here.
